# Using the same file names in assemble causing compiled static templates to be wrong

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

I am having some problems with assemble when using the same filename for the data object being passed into the relative templates...

First off the grunt snippet:

```
 assemble: {
        options: {
          layout: "src/responsive/layouts/default.hbs",
          partials: 'src/responsive/modules/**/*.hbs',
          data: 'src/responsive/data/**/*.json',
          flatten: false,
        },
        pages: {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'src/responsive/pages',
          src: '**/*.hbs',
          dest: 'src/'
        }
}
```

In my pages folder I have index.hbs

```
{{#index }} 
  {{> hero }}
  {{> rp }}
  {{> feature }}
  {{> social }}
{{/index }}
```

And insurance/index.hbs

```
{{#index }} 
  {{> hero }}
  {{> shout }}
  {{> social }}
{{/index }}
```

And the data folder is structured as follows:

```
-responsive
--data
---index.json
---insurance
----index.json
```

Basically I have one json per page and want the json file to match the template. However, as they are both called 'index' the templates are using data from the wrong files. If I rename `insurance/index.hbs` to be `insurance/foo.hbs` and have `insurance/foo.json` with the following:

```
{{#foo}} 
  {{> hero }}
  {{> shout }}
  {{> social }}
{{/foo}}
```

It all works fine but I need to have the ability to use the same file names just be in a different directory.

Im at a loss as to how to fix this. Any guidance much appricated.

A.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're using `index` in the templates in the examples. Is `{{#index}}` referencing a data file, or a variable on the context? (happy to explain if that doesn't make sense).

The duplicate-name issue is something we've discussed in the past, and in a nutshell it's tough to work around the issue with vanilla partials. e.g. there is no logic in partials, they just use the context passed to them. As for the data, similar challenge, it's just an object, so duplicate properties won't work.

Here are two potential solutions:

#### Use helpers instead of partials

Using helpers you can achieve the same thing as partials, but you'll also be able to add some logic to use some additional piece of information to help differentiate the files (e.g. since basename isn't good enough int this case).

You could create a helper to filter out files based on a property in the front matter, or create a helper that allows you to test file paths with a regex pattern defined on the hash. something like (you'll need to tweak based on the rest of your setup):

```
{{#test page.dirname 'foo'}}
  {{#index }} 
    {{> hero }}
    {{> shout }}
    {{> social }}
  {{/index }}
{{/test}}
```

#### Or, try wrapping the block with helpers

Alternatively you could try using the `{{#is}}...{{/is}}` helper or another comparison helper that can screen out partials/files based on additional (conditional) information. (btw, you can use any property on the context in your comparisons. whether it's in front matter or part of the file path is arbitrary and up to you).  Example:

```
{{#is data.slug 'foo'}}
  {{#index }} 
    {{> hero }}
    {{> shout }}
    {{> social }}
  {{/index }}
{{/test}}
```

Also, although I'm wrapping the `index` block in my examples, if you use helpers you'd probably use a block helper instead of `index`, but I don't know enough about your setup to say for sure. hope this helps

---

**EDIT:** Don't do the above recommendations. I wasn't thinking clearly when I wrote this earlier. The above solutions won't work for filtering partials. For filtering pages they are worth considering.  More specifically, by the time a partial reaches the helpers the partials in the array will have already been reduced to a basename, thus any "dupes" will have already been filtered out before they reach the helpers.

You could create an `include` helper and add an `includes` property to the assemble options where the glob patterns for includes would be defined, then do some custom logic in the helper to figure out paths, etc. But my recommendation is to create a middleware to do what you need. See Assemble's [i18n middleware](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-middleware-i18n/blob/master/index.js), it's probably the best example I can think of to get you started in the right direction.